Helm dependency condition in dependency chart (not working as expected)
So I have a base chart with Chart.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
description: Core Helm Chart
name: core
version: 0.5.4
dependencies:
- name: microservice-a
  version: "0.0.1"
  repository: oci://123.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
  condition: microService.a.enabled
- name: microservice-b
  version: "0.0.1"
  repository: oci://123.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
  condition: microService.b.enabled

and it has build in values with:
microService:
  a:
    enabled: false
  b:
    enabled: false

when used with helm template. it works as expected: the microService charts are not rendered.
Now when I use the base chart as a dependency:
apiVersion: v1
description: Core Helm Chart
name: test
version: 0.0.1
dependencies:
- name: core
  version: "0.5.4"
  repository: oci://123.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

without any values it renders both microservice A and B charts, same thing happens when I use:
--set microService.a.enabled=false or --set core.microService.a.enabled=false
(or set this in values.yaml
Why are the microService charts always rendered in that case?

The issue was apiVersion, dependency conditions are working only on v2
apiVersion: v2
description: Core Helm Chart
name: test
version: 0.0.1
dependencies:
- name: core
  version: "0.5.4"
  repository: oci://123.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

works as expected!
(leaving it for further "strugglers" here)
